# Why does pyserial read as b'number'

Tags: file, text, save, pyserial

I want to save those values in a file.txt, when the program saves them, it saves b'number', I'd like to plot those values but I can't with b'number' I just want number saved

Answer (score 0):

You need to transform your input data into numbers because in your case pyserial is sending binary data, not prepared numeric. Also, byte order matters, you should specify whether it is 'big-endian', 'little-endian', 'native' etc.
If you are using Python 3.x, your job can be done this way:

```
values = [int.from_bytes(binary_number, 'little') for binary_number in binary_data]
```

And plot your `values`.
Hope this helps.